# convert a json to array in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

how i can to change a key on json to array with one value in laravel.
i send api for android app and i need to send all data In the form of list to read in android.
for example:

```html
{
  data1: {
    d1: "aaaaaaaaaaa"
  }
  data2: [
    d11: "ccccccccccc"
    d12: "jjjjjjjjjjj"
  ]
}
```

convert to:

```html
{
  data1: [
    d1: "aaaaaaaaaaa"
  ]
  data2: [
    d11: "ccccccccccc"
    d12: "jjjjjjjjjjj"
  ]
}
```

change data1 to array and use this [].

Comment: JSON arrays never have key value pairs. Your JSON is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

you need to provide second parameter of the `json_decode()` function which is as assoc flag

> assoc
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

so in your case
`json_decode($yourJson, true)`